# How to detect fake faces using Haarcascade in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, face-detection

I am doing a project to detect and recognize face. This I am doing on `raspberry pi 4` with `4`gb RAM. I have used `haarcascade` to detect face and using [python face recognition](https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/) library to recognize the detected face. So far I am getting good speed on `raspberry pi 4` and `pi camera`.

I have also noticed that face detection and recognition can also happen if someone shows some photo of a person while that person is not actually present. Is there any way we can detect fake faces I have read many articles but I am not sure if that can be run on raspberry pi as it do not have much CPU power. Is there any method of detecting fake faces which can be run on raspberry pi.?

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely difficult to prevent the detection of faces on something like an image from a phone or from a picture, and this is because the input is in 2D. In order to verify that a detected face is indeed a face, you would need a camera that can not only capture images in 2D but also capture depth information. A depth camera is present in devices like the Xbox Kinect and the iPhone Face ID camera.

If you do have an RGB-D camera, i.e., a camera that can capture depth information, you could use convolutional neural networks to detect and verify faces. Unfortunately, there aren't many publicly available RGB-D face detection and recognition models, so you might have to train your own.

In terms of CPU power, the Raspberry Pi should be able to run small neural networks without a problem, but you might need some sort of external neural inference computer, like the Intel Neural Compute Stick. However, before buying anything, you should try running something on the Raspberry Pi first.

Comment: Why do you need a depth camera.?

Comment: depth camera is used to calculate depth i.e. in this case distance of the detected face from camera, which I don't think cannot be used to detect fake or real face.?

Comment: The depth camera can be used to determine if the face is on a flat paper/screen or is a real face, so it can be used to detect a fake or real face.